# Variables for LaTeX in Lyx?

Tags: tables, lyx, text, environment-variables

I created a table in LaTeX in the Premables.

Original code below, Premables without the code, and a PDF output of it -
I put placeholders (just text) for different kinds of text that I want to put in the table (denoted in [X] where X is some text:

[image]

My question is:

Is it possible to create some variables/something else which will enable me to edit those texts directly, in LyX's user interface?
What I want to do is not edit/write the the code every single time, and just write the texts, to avoid going to the Premables every time I create a new document in which I want this table.

Comment: See also ERT to include LaTeX code directly in the text.

Comment: I don't know if I have understand your needs, but you can create a `preamble.tex` with you costumized code and put only `\input{preamble.tex}` in your LyX preamble.

Comment: What does this command do? Does it just load the `premable.tex` file into my LyX file?

I want to do something like sending values into functions, such that what would be printed would be the values that I sent.
Like in programming: `print("hey")`, where `print` is the function, and `"hey"` is a text input.

Comment: To ping a user, you have to put @ before his/her nickname, for example @CarLaTeX. Yes, `\input{...}` only load `preamble.tex` into your file. If you want to do a `\newcommand`, you can put it both in your `preamble.tex` or directly in your LyX file using ERT.

Comment: I think you should probably look into making modules. I don't know much about that, but there is some info in e.g. Help->Customization.